# How to query across multiple databases in Apache Superset?

Tags: apache-superset

I need to display charts based on SQL queries, but I have to write queries to join tables which are from different databases. Is there anyway I can do it in Apache Superset?

I looked into Trino, but wondering if there is a better way as we are running Superset on Kubernetes and we have to deploy Trino in our Kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I think currently you can't query more than one DB at once.
A workaround would be to use something similar to [Postgres dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-function.html) function on your main query to retrieve data from a remote DB.

Another solutions would be to (1) create a view (materialized view) or (2) to generate a foreign table on your main DB with required data from the remote DB.
Then, you can query only from one DB and use Superset filters.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the materialized view method ? I am not sure if dblink would work on superset